# Compass и ScSS, зачем тогда в gulp scss плагин?

Tags: css, scss, compass

Я в **gulp** настроил плагин **gulp-sass**, который из **ScSS**, генерирует  **CSS** код. Зачем мне тогда нужен в **Compass**  этот генератор, можно его как-то удалить, или лучше удалить **gulp-sass**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос как минимум странный. Compass ставится, если мне не изменяет память, как gem-плагин для Ruby. Вроде бы есть отдельный compass-пакет для npm, но он только как обёртка над соответствующим гемом. Для gulp-sass он не нужен, так что можете его смело удалять.

Причём, замечу, gulp-sass работает в разы быстрее, чем соответствующий реализация Sass/Compass на Ruby, потому что gulp-sass есть обёртка над node-sass, который является обёрткой над libsass, который в свою очередь написан на C/C++.

Comment: Compass не для Ruby, а для css. http://itsurface.ru/sass-compass-install-setting/    А как же все уникальные функции compass-а? Крозбраузерность и прочие?

Comment: @Niko_D Вы не поняли. Compass — это gem для Ruby. Посмотрите сами по ссылке, что вы дали, как происходит установка. Т. е., когда вся эта шарманка будет работать, для того, чтобы перегнать ваш SCSS в CSS будет запускаться Ruby и всё такое. Имплементация на JS (C/C++) работает быстрее.

Comment: @Niko_D Вы сейчас о префиксах? Вроде бы, что-то из коробки умеет и сам gulp-sass, но на крайний случай никто не мешает прогнать через autoprefixer: https://www.npmjs.com/package/autoprefixer

Comment: Странно, в процессе установки gulp и сопутствующих механизмов, я вроде бы устанавливал Ruby... Но не моуг вспомнить что именно там работает на руби. Так что, компасс уже умирает?

Comment: Igor Adamenko - И еще я не понимаю, причем тут скорость компиляции? Для меня не будет никакой разницы, толе это будет 3 секунды, толе 30 (с тем учетом что будут плюшки)

Comment: @Niko_D Gulp абсолютно никак не связан с Ruby, потому вы ставили что-то не то. Компасс не то чтобы умирает, но его «плюшки» не сильно уже нужны кому-то, ибо с тем же галпом можно настроить что угодно, как хочется. Скорость же компиляции при том, что, обычно, людям нужно иметь обновление страницы в браузере на лету. Изменил SCSS → посмотрел, что получилось. И если всё это работает дольше 0,5–1 секунды — это уже неудобно. С Ruby так и есть, с JS — всё быстрее. Потому и говорят о скорости.

Comment: Спасибо. А вот еще, установил autoprefixer, но он не добавляет префиксы к border-radius, хотя если  display: flex; в сss написать, то к нему добавляет. В настройках установил - browsers: ['last 16 versions'],

Comment: @Niko_D думаю, это уже не относится к текущему вопросу. однако, как вариант, можно проверить по этому пакету: https://github.com/ai/browserslist что возвращает правило last 16 versions. как бы, префиксы для border-radius нужны только для старых версий фф и пр. + ie8